# Export table to excel symfony2

Tags: php, symfony

I am trying to use Symfony2
how can I export an html table to an Excel file with php
who can help me

Answer (score 3):

You can use Symfony2 bundles with such a functionality.

For example: https://github.com/liuggio/ExcelBundle should do.

It provides dependency injection and easy creation of [PHPExcel](http://phpexcel.codeplex.com/) objects. Use composer to manage dependencies and automatically load required libraries.

Comment: hello I used this method to export a table I'm displaying the content but not much I have, as séparteur: (

Comment: $filename = "export_".date("Y_m_d").".xls"; 
    $response=$this->render('AdminBlogBundle:GestionAlerte:excel.html.twig', array('listes'=>$listes)); 
     $response->headers->set('Content-Type', 'text/vnd.ms-excel; charset=utf-8');
     $response->headers->set('Content-Disposition', 'attachment; filename='.$filename);
 $response->headers->set('Pragma', 'public'); $response->headers->set('Cache-Control', 'maxage=1');

Answer (score 2):

Try [PHPExcel](http://phpexcel.codeplex.com/). It has support for most of the frequently used Excel features.